# CSS Underline Colour without Border-bottom

Tags: html, css, underline, text-decorations

I'm trying to style a link inside of a list and because of how I've got other styles going, I cannot use `border-bottom: 1px solid #0da4d3`. Now I've done some research and found `text-decoration-color` but that's only for Firefox so it won't work for me.

I'm looking for a way I can change the underline colour that will work in the 5 major browsers (I can live without IE). Is there a way I can do this? I'm open to any added HTML or JavaScript as well.

This is a fiddle of what I have currently got: http://jsfiddle.net/yhqf5z2n/

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to adding html markup, you can change the color of the link underline like this :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kemfppux/)**

*HTML :*

```
<a href="#"><span>Link</span></a>
```

*CSS :*

```
a{
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:red;
}
a>span{
    color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way than using `border-bottom`. You can use a pseudo element and give it a `border-bottom`, or you can also use `box-shadow:inset` ...

Check out this fiddle:
     [pseudo elements](http://jsfiddle.net/6YJHM/)

Comment: You're missing your links... However before I even read this I found a page mentioning `box-shadow` and tried it out. Gave me an interesting effect though not what I want exactly.

Comment: i've added the link. check it out

Comment: @Hamix I did say I wasn't particularly worried about IE. Besides 7 & 8 are older versions now.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what I wanted but playing around with `box-shadow` I found a pretty cool effect (it's animated on WordPress) that I'm going to stick with.

```
box-shadow: inset 0 -7px 0 0 #0da4d3;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yhqf5z2n/1/